# When I use lcd.setCursor(0,3) with a 20x4 I2C LCD it prints to line 2, is this a bug?

Tags: arduino, lcd

I'm currently setting up a display LCD using the 20x4 LCD by Sainsmart. I'm using the LiquidCrystal_I2C library (http://www.dfrobot.com/image/data/TOY0046/LiquidCrystal_I2Cv1-1.rar) and up to now everything worked well. I am trying to print 4 lines every second using the following code (killSwitch returns a boolean):

```
while (killSwitch()) {
  i++;
  lcd.clear();
  lcd.print(i);
  lcd.setCursor(0,1);
  lcd.print("RPM:");
  lcd.setCursor(0,2);
  lcd.print("Speed:");
  lcd.setCursor(0,3);
  lcd.print("Fuel:");
  delay(1000); 
}
```

For some reason the 4th line (for "Fuel") overwrites the 2nd line (for "RPM"). Interestingly, when I try to print only a single line at a time I can print to the last line, so I don't think there's anything wrong with the device itself. Any thoughts?

EDIT:

```
LiquidCrystal_I2C lcd(0x3F, 20, 4);
void setup() {
  lcd.init();
  lcd.backlight();
  lcd.print("ON");
  lcd.setCursor(0,2);
  lcd.print("LCD DISPLAY");
  delay(1000);
  lcd.clear();
  lcd.setCursor(0,2);
  lcd.print("READ OWNER MANUAL");
  lcd.setCursor(0,3);
  lcd.print("BEFORE OPERATION");
  delay(1000);
  lcd.clear();
}
```

Comment: Can you share the code where you are doing the setup of the display?

Comment: Did you make sure to do `lcd.begin(20, 4);`?

Answer (score 2):

I had exactly the same issue.
lcd.print (0,1) and lcd.print(0,3) seem to refer to the same line.

Say on Line (0,1) I have the text "Hello World"
And on Line (0,3) want "Test"
The output is: "Testo World".

By adding

```
lcd.begin(20, 4);
```

After `lcd.init();`

it solved it,

Answer (score 0):

The first and last lines are 0 and 3, **not** 1 and 4, so your row 2 is the third line of the display.

Comment: Please could you elaborate on your answer by supplying some more information about where they're going wrong. It seems their issue is related to the "4th line" overriding the "2nd line", so is this really an index issue?

Comment: I refer to them as 1st and 4th, referring to index 0 and 3; I know that the device is zero-indexed

Answer (score 0):

Not a bug. `setCursor(x,y)` accepts x and y coordinates, which are zero based indexes.

`setCursor(0,0)` moves to the first character on the first line.

`setCursor(5,1)` moves to the sixth character on the second line.

`setCursor(19,3)` moves to the very last character in the bottom right corner of your 20x4 LCD.

Comment: I had been using zero-based index: I never use setCursor(x,y) beyond (0,3)